# How to a convert a vector of labels into a binary vector in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

suppose i have A=ones(10,1)*10
then what does this do eye(10)(A,:) ??

i know eye gives a 10,10 identity matrix but i am not really sure what the above code is doing.
and what is the equivalent code in Matlab?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`A=ones(10,1)*10` just makes a column matrix (10 rows, 1 column) of 10s.

`eye(10)` makes a 10x10 identity matrix.

The `(A,:)` indexes into the identity matrix you just made. The `A` here acts as a *numeric* index into the `eye(10)` matrix. Suppose `A` was just 10. Then the `myMatrix(A,:)` would select the 10th row of `myMatrix`. Since `A` is 10 *rows* of 10, `myMatrix(A,:)` selects the 10th row of `myMatrix`, *10 times*. So you get back out the 10th row of `eye(10)` 10 times.

It may be less confusing if you do `A=ones(5,1)*10` and have a look at `eye(10)(A,:)`; notice that you now only get the 10th row of `A` 5 times.

You can't do this as such in Matlab because it doesn't let you do the one-hit `eye(10)(A,:)`. You have to do it in two steps:

```
A = ones(10,1)*10
I = eye(10)
I(A,:)
```

[More on various types of matrix indexing in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html).